# MAVEN :- Could not resolve dependencies for project

Tags: java, spring, maven, dependencies

I hope some one facing the same issue to resolving the dependencies. `POM.xml` file mentioned below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.shopizer</groupId>
    <artifactId>habbit</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.0</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>habbit-core</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>habbit-core</name>
<url>http://www.shopizer.com</url>

<properties>
    <coverage.lines>.00</coverage.lines>
    <coverage.branches>.00</coverage.branches>
    <google-client-maps-services-version>0.1.6</google-client-maps-services-version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <!-- jpa, crud repository -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-ehcache -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- sm-core-model -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.shopizer</groupId>
        <artifactId>habbit-core-model</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- sm-core-modules -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.shopizer</groupId>
        <artifactId>habbit-core-modules</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- canadapost -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.shopizer</groupId>
        <artifactId>shopizer-shipping-canadapost-module</artifactId>
        <version>${shopizer-canadapost.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Google Map API -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.maps</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-maps-services</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
        <artifactId>kie-ci</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
        <artifactId>drools-decisiontables</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
        <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
        <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!--spring integration -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
        <artifactId>kie-spring</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- end rules engine -->

    <!-- Infinispan -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
        <artifactId>infinispan-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
        <artifactId>infinispan-tree</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-collections4 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
        <!--<version>${commons-collections4.version}</version> -->
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-validator/commons-validator -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
        <!--<version>${commons-validator.version}</version> -->

        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.freemarker/freemarker -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
        <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context-support -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-s3 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-ses -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-ses</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- google cloud storage -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-cloud-storage</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Payment dependencies -->

    <!-- Paypal -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.paypal.sdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>merchantsdk</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Stripe -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.stripe</groupId>
        <artifactId>stripe-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Braintree -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.braintreepayments.gateway</groupId>
        <artifactId>braintree-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Invoices -->
    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId> <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId> 
        </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.jopendocument</groupId> <artifactId>jOpenDocument</artifactId> 
        </dependency> -->

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.maxmind.geoip2/geoip2 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.maxmind.geoip2</groupId>
        <artifactId>geoip2</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- google cloud storage -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
    <!-- Up to date for GCP storage issue -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- tests dependencies -->
    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- H2 DB -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Elastic search -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.shopizer</groupId>
        <artifactId>sm-search</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
                <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

when I run command mvn clean install:-

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Inspecting build with total of 6 modules...
[INFO] Installing Nexus Staging features:
[INFO]   ... total of 6 executions of maven-deploy-plugin replaced with nexus-staging-maven-plugin
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO]
[INFO] habbit                                                             [pom]
[INFO] habbit-core-model                                                  [jar]
[INFO] habbit-core-modules                                                [jar]
[INFO] habbit-core                                                        [jar]
[INFO] habbit-shop-model                                                  [jar]
[INFO] habbit-shop                                                        [jar]
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------< com.shopizer:habbit >-------------------------
[INFO] Building habbit 2.12.0                                             [1/6]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0:clean (default-clean) @ habbit ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.3:prepare-agent (default-prepare-agent) @ habbit ---
[INFO] argLine set to -javaagent:C:\\Users\\Hp\\.m2\\repository\\org\\jacoco\\org.jacoco.agent\\0.8.3\\org.jacoco.agent-0.8.3-runtime.jar=destfile=D:\\myProject\\h
abbit\\target\\jacoco.exec
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------< com.shopizer:habbit-core-model >-------------------
[INFO] Building habbit-core-model 2.12.0                                  [2/6]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0:clean (default-clean) @ habbit-core-model ---
[INFO] Deleting D:\myProject\habbit\habbit-core-model\target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.3:prepare-agent (default-prepare-agent) @ habbit-core-model ---
[INFO] argLine set to -javaagent:C:\\Users\\Hp\\.m2\\repository\\org\\jacoco\\org.jacoco.agent\\0.8.3\\org.jacoco.agent-0.8.3-runtime.jar=destfile=D:\\myProject\\h
abbit\\habbit-core-model\\target\\jacoco.exec
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:resources (default-resources) @ habbit-core-model ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\myProject\habbit\habbit-core-model\src\main\resources
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\myProject\habbit\habbit-core-model\src\main\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ habbit-core-model ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 182 source files to D:\myProject\habbit\habbit-core-model\target\classes
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------< com.shopizer:habbit-core-modules >------------------
[INFO] Building habbit-core-modules 2.12.0                                [3/6]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0:clean (default-clean) @ habbit-core-modules ---
[INFO] Deleting D:\myProject\habbit\habbit-core-modules\target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.3:prepare-agent (default-prepare-agent) @ habbit-core-modules ---
[INFO] argLine set to -javaagent:C:\\Users\\Hp\\.m2\\repository\\org\\jacoco\\org.jacoco.agent\\0.8.3\\org.jacoco.agent-0.8.3-runtime.jar=destfile=D:\\myProject\\h
abbit\\habbit-core-modules\\target\\jacoco.exec
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:resources (default-resources) @ habbit-core-modules ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\myProject\habbit\habbit-core-modules\src\main\resources
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\myProject\habbit\habbit-core-modules\src\main\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ habbit-core-modules ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 14 source files to D:\myProject\habbit\habbit-core-modules\target\classes
[INFO]
[INFO] ----------------------< com.shopizer:habbit-core >----------------------
[INFO] Building habbit-core 2.12.0                                        [4/6]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary for habbit 2.12.0:
[INFO]
[INFO] habbit ............................................. SUCCESS [  2.919 s]
[INFO] habbit-core-model .................................. SUCCESS [ 14.010 s]
[INFO] habbit-core-modules ................................ SUCCESS [  2.125 s]
[INFO] habbit-core ........................................ FAILURE [  2.078 s]
[INFO] habbit-shop-model .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] habbit-shop ........................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  24.245 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-05-22T15:12:57+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project habbit-core: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.shopizer:habbit-core:jar:2.12.0: Failed to collect dependenci
es at com.shopizer:shopizer-shipping-canadapost-module:jar:2.11.0 -> com.shopizer:sm-core-model:jar:2.10.0: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.shopizer:sm-
core-model:jar:2.10.0: Failure to find com.shopizer:shopizer:pom:2.10.0 in https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/ was cached in the local reposit
ory, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of oss-sonatype has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <args> -rf :habbit-core
```

Comment: Please add full log output + JDK version and Maven version?

Comment: The artifact `com.shopizer:shopizer:pom:2.10.0` cannot be found. So, did you configure the right repository for this artifact?

Comment: Try to find the parent pom dependency on
https://oss.sonatype.org
but could not find there.
You should check, and add the correct reposties.

Answer (score 0):

Remove canadapost-module from dependencies.